# preg_match_all и данные в $matches?

Tags: php

Пишу систему роутеров, есть такой код (проверка url):

```
if (preg_match_all(
    '#^'.$uri.'$#', $currentUrl, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER
 )) {
     $matches['call'] = $v['call'];
     $matches['middleware'] = $v['middleware'];
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($matches);
 }
```

Если у меня указано больше 1го роутера:

```
Route::get('/', '\app\controllers\index\MainController@methodName');
Route::get('/url', '\app\controllers\index\MainController@methodName');
```

, то результат ($matches) будет пустым если будет использован не последний роутер.
То есть, если я использую /url - все корректно работает, если / - в $matches пустота.

Ниже этого условия так же есть print_r($matches)
Если указанно больше 1го роутера, то в условие (if (preg_match...) print_r($matches) - содержит информацию для любого url (если совпадает), а print_r($matches) который уже ниже условия - не содержит информации.

То есть:
Если указанно больше 1го роутера, то $matches содержит информацию в if () , ниже - нету.

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => url
    )

)
// второй print_r
 Array
 (
 )
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать из шаблона символы начала и конца строки: "^" и "$".

Comment: @Эдуард не помогло.

Comment: Вот такой вариант шаблона попробуйте: '#'. preg_quote($uri, '#') .'#'

Comment: @Эдуард тоже нет, увы.

Comment: напишите пожалуйста, что требуется получить? Т.е., исходный и искомый текст.

Comment: @Эдуард кажется проблема вообще не в этом, так как preg_match работает аналогично.
Мне нужно найти  роутер который совпадает с текущим url.
/url = Route::get('/url').
Он находит, но в случае если указанно больше 1го роутера, то сработает только последний.

Answer (score 0):

Не внимательный я:с

Не сделал break;

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант :

```
$uri = '\app\controllers\index\MainController@methodName';
$route = explode('\\', trim($uri, '\\'));

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($route); echo '</pre>';
/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "app"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "controllers"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "index"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "MainController@methodName"
}
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо ;)
Подвела моя невнимательность